# Change management on entities using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a requirement to implement a change management system on my domain models. I somehow built a solution that leverages an Efcore interceptor that overrides OnSavingChangesAsync method, creates a new change request object, serializes as json the current values and original value of the entity being changed and stores them as properties of the change request object, then I mark the entity being changed as detached and only persist the change request item.

After the change request gets an approved status I serialize back the values of the changed entity and add/update it on the database.

This works well in simple scenarios where I only have an enetity being changed/added that doesnt include navigation properties. With navigation this gets a lot more complicated, especially if the navigation property is a collection.
I didnt found a way to solve this scenario.

Does anyone implement a similar system, what was your approach?

Comment: You should probably move one layer up and deal with these requirements in the business logic. That being said, I have an auditing system similar to what you described on EF6: every table has audit columns such as `ModifiedOnUtc` and a "mirror" table where I save the original record before any update. You can then (non-trivially) reconstruct the history of any entity and their 1-N relations. You could achieve the same for N-M relations by adding the same mechanism on the join tables but you would lose the benefits of EF handling the join tables automatically

Comment: Could you provide some guidance on how to build this? A sample/demo code will be appreciated.

Comment: I override `SaveChanges()` and do something like this: `var changedExamples = ChangeTracker
    .Entries<ExampleEntity>()
    .Where(x => x.State is EntityState.Modified || x.State is EntityState.Deleted);

foreach (var entry in changedExamples)
{
    var original = entry.OriginalValues.ToObject() as ExampleEntity;

    _historyContext.ExampleEntities_History.Add(new ExampleEntity_History
    {
        // Copy relevant properties
    });
}`

Comment: So you want to audit your changes in ef core ? This might be interesting for you https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET